# alias - open vs code workspace if file exist

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I am trying to open a workspace, if workspace file exist, from an alias:

This does not work, when caled from the alias "co"

```
alias co=[ -f $(basename $(PWD)).code-workspace ] && code $(basename $(PWD)).code-workspace || code .
```

But it works from ther terminal:

```
[ -f $(basename $(PWD)).code-workspace ] && code $(basename $(PWD)).code-workspace || code .
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string needs to be quoted.

```
alias co='[ -f $(basename $(PWD)).code-workspace ] && code $(basename $(PWD)).code-workspace || code .'
```

However, a function is a lot better. No need to cram everything into one line.

```
co() {
    if [ -f "$(basename "$PWD")".code-workspace ]; then
        code "$(basename "$PWD")".code-workspace
    else
        code .
    fi
}
```

It's best to use if/else rather than `&&` and `||`. [Greg's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Grouping_Statements) says:

> Using conditional operators is easy and terse if we want to do simple error checking. Things get a bit more dangerous, though, when we want to run multiple statements if a condition holds true, or if we need to evaluate multiple conditions.
>
> ...
>
> In general, it's *not* a good idea to string together multiple different control operators in one command. `&&` and `||` are quite useful in simple cases, but not in complex ones.